# JPA 2.0 multitenancy relations without vendor specific features

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, multi-tenant

I try to implement multi tenancy support.
Given restrictions and constraints:

- JPA 2.0 (Java EE 6) without vendor specific features (Hibernate, EclipseLink, ...)
- Shared scheme multi tenancy level. Basically every table has an unique string and tenant discriminator as primary key (Id, TenantKey)

My first try is to map the id and the tenant key as composite primary key and @IdClass. So all my entities are basically looking like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = any.EntityPK)
public class Entity
{
  private String id;
  private String tenantKey;

  //....
}
```

Unfortunately, with this solution, its not possible to map any relation because the tenant key can't be mapped twice. For example, I have following "OneToMany" relation on the database:

```
Table A (ID, tenantKey, AnyColumnTableA)
Table B (ID, tenantKey, AnyColumnTableB, ForeignKey_ID_TableA)
```

Example data:

```
Table A(23, t01, Hello)
Table B(44, t01, Foo, 23)
Table B(45, t01, Bar, 23)
```

I don't see the correct JPA mapping for this specific "OneToMany" relation. JPA requires a redundant column for the tenant key in Table B, which I can't provide:

```
Table B(ID, tenantKey, AnyColumnTableB, ForeignKey_ID_TableA, ForeignKey_TenantKey_TableA)
e.g. Table B(23, t01, Foo, 23, t01)
```

The same problem does occur on other relationship types too. I think this is a common problem and maybe I'm on the wrong way with my solution. So please either show me the correct mapping or guide me to the correct approach to implement multitenancy support on scheme level.